# Box2d C++ AccessViolation using b2fixture out of method

Tags: c++, box2d, access-violation

Im creating box2d polygons, i would like to create the fixture outside of the method that attaches the fixture to the body, but when i do this i get a access violation.

i have stepped through the code and box2d is definitely getting the fixture object.

when i attach the fixture to the body inside the method it works fine. when i try in the calling method it throws access violation error

```
    b2FixtureDef* LineSegment::GenerateFixture(b2Vec2 vertices[4],b2Body* body,b2World* world){
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    //bodyDef.type = b2_kinematicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(_currentStepStartPosition.x,_currentStepStartPosition.y);
    body =world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    int32 count = 4;
    b2PolygonShape polygon;
    polygon.Set(vertices, count);
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef2;
    fixtureDef2.shape = &polygon;
    fixtureDef2.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef2.friction = 0.3f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef2);/// works if i attatch the fixture here here
    return &fixtureDef2;
}
```

the calling method it fails when i attach the fixture here

```
    bool LineSegment::GenerateNextBody(b2Body* retBody){
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(_currentStepStartPosition.x,_currentStepStartPosition.y);
    retBody =world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    _currentStep++;
    b2Vec2 vertices[4];
    if(_inclinePerStep != 0){
    GetVertsInclineSquare(vertices,_stepWidth,_thickness,_inclinePerStep);
    }else{
        GetVertsSquare(vertices,_stepWidth,_thickness);
    }
    if(_currentStep == 1){
        _GameWorldVerticies[0] =b2Vec2((_currentStepStartPosition.x+vertices[0].x)*PTM_RATIO,(_currentStepStartPosition.y+vertices[0].y)*PTM_RATIO);
        _GameWorldVerticies[3] =b2Vec2((_currentStepStartPosition.x+vertices[3].x)*PTM_RATIO,(_currentStepStartPosition.y+vertices[3].y)*PTM_RATIO);

    }
    b2FixtureDef* fixture = GenerateFixture(vertices,retBody,world);

    //retBody->CreateFixture(fixture); throws a access violation if i attatch the fixture here
    _currentStepStartPosition.x += vertices[2].x+(vertices[2].x);
    _currentStepStartPosition.y +=(_inclinePerStep/2);
    if(_steps <= _currentStep){
        _GameWorldVerticies[1] =b2Vec2((_currentStepStartPosition.x+vertices[1].x)*PTM_RATIO,(_currentStepStartPosition.y+vertices[1].y)*PTM_RATIO);
        _GameWorldVerticies[2] =b2Vec2((_currentStepStartPosition.x+vertices[2].x)*PTM_RATIO,(_currentStepStartPosition.y+vertices[2].y)*PTM_RATIO);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

new snippet

```
        b2FixtureDef* fixtureDef2 = new b2FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef2->shape = &polygon;
    fixtureDef2->density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef2->friction = 0.3f;
    //body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef2);/// works if i attatch the fixture here here
    return fixtureDef2;
```

Comment: Have you tried running your program in a debugger? Then you could catch the error and examine variables to see if they all look okay (i.e. no `NULL` pointers etc.).

Comment: i have i know where the program crashes and i dont see anything that could cause a null pointer. should i paste the debug data(screenshots and where it crashes in box2d lib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you return a pointer to a local variable in `GenerateFixture`, which is *undefined behavior*. The variable `fixtureDef2` is on the stack, and when the function returns that area of the stack is not valid any more. When you late call the `CreateFixture` function, the pointer will now point into the area of the stack for *that* function.

To solve this you could create it on the heap with e.g. `new`.

Comment: so i tried with the new keyword and it gives me the same issue. but judging from your answer what i am doing is not best practice. would it maybe be better to pass the fixture object as a parameter, and let the data get populated by the called method ? rather then returning?

Comment: @Billybonks It's not close to "best practice", returning pointers (or references) to local variables _will_ cause bad things to happen sooner or later. Passing a reference as argument is also an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Billybonks In your new code you are _still_ using pointers to local variables, with the `polygon` variable.

Comment: ya i see, i think i will just then combine this method with the caller method, because if i remove all the local pointers then it will basically be doing nothing